# How To Bypass Method Like (!Page.IsPost Back) On Redirecting From Some Other Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to do but fail i want to by pass method as we do using (!Page.IsPost Back) but on redirecting from some page... .

Example,

Form A has a method name Process() i want to by bass this method when i come to this form from form B i use this way to do on Ispostback,

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
Public Void Process()
{
.
.
.
}
}
```

Hopes for Your Suggestions

Comment: Try the Page.PreviousPage property. I think this will only work if you're being transferred from another page handled by your IIS.

Comment: If the current page is being rendered as a result of a direct request (not a transfer or cross-post from another page), the PreviousPage property contains null. - [Page.PreviousPage Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx)

Comment: BTW, adding "C# Web App" to the end of your title makes it hard to read. Keep that information in the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach: you could append a query string to the uri. If that query string exists, don't call the method. A direct request without the query string would call it, so the current behavior is the default.

Comment: This is a very easy option, but remember that's it also available to attentive users even when they aren't coming from the prior page, and so if used improperly can be a security issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following approaches:

1. `if (Page.PreviousPage.Title == "Your Previous Page Title")` You can use this approach only, if you use `Server.Transfer` to navigate the page, otherwise `PreviousPage` property will be `null`
2. **Using QueryString:**

   Previous Page:

   `Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx?previousPage=MyPreviousPage");`

   Next Page:

   `if(Request.QueryString["previousPage"] != null && Request.QueryString["previousPage"] == "MyPreviousPage" )`
3. **Using Session:**

   Previous Page:

   `Session["PreviousPage"] = "MyPreviousPage";
    Response.Redirect("WebForm1.aspx");`

   Next Page:

   `if (Session["PreviousPage"] != null && Session["PreviousPage"] == "MyPreviousPage")`

Comment: Wouldn't `Page.PreviousPage.Title` potentially throw a `NullReferenceException`?